# How to test that Python and the standard libaries are properly installed?

Tags: python, testing, installation

I'm sometimes sitting in front of a machine where I'm not sure whether Python with the standard libraries is fully installed.(*)

**Is there an easily accessible Python script (separately for Python 2 and Python 3) which checks that interpreter and the standard libraries are properly installed?**

I'm not after the full test suit of the Python source, rather a one-file script which checks main functionalities.

---

(*) Scenarios where I might be unsure what's installed: Frequent installing and uninstalling of stuff through the package manager (e.g. setup.exe for Cygwin)  or the machine is a single-board computer (e.g. Rasberry Pi) where by default everything *might* be installed - or not.

Comment: `make test` from the source code, probably?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was hoping for something easier: Just one script or a build-in function in the Python2/3 command.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I believe it's `make test`, as per the [build instructions](https://github.com/python/cpython#build-instructions).

Comment: @halloleo Good question. None I'm aware of... besides this.

Comment: @halloleo, how are you installing these libraries? A package manager shouldn't be removing necessary libraries for an installed package. **Shouldn't** is obviously idealistically speaking. If you're installing from source, `make test` is your friend. I don't believe most of the tests are installed, so my recommendation would be to write a script copying most of the code for the high-level tests.

Comment: Most of the tests can be found here. They should just run as-is, for the most part, requiring little-to-no-modification:
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/test

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh That's the point. Everything should be there, but would be nice to have an easy quick check of main functionalities...

Comment: Just cleared up the question regarding the ambiguities pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: I don't think a `is_everything_i_want_installed()` function would make sense.

Comment: @halloleo, to your revised update: no. You could likely modify the core test suite with minimal effort to do what you want, but some tests are version-specific, and tests aren't installed in package managers by default. Sorry.